# How to update and display a ProgressBar in each row of a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-progressbar

I want to display a ProgressBar in each view of my ListView.

I have created a holder class which extends AsyncTask for the purpose of updating the progress bar in the view.

My current implementation work unless I try to scroll the ListView. After scrolling the wrong progress bars are updated and some of the previously finished progress bars are started from the position of whichever is currently running.

I am extending BaseAdapter, my getView method is as follows:

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = li.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        ProgressBarTask asyncViewHolder = mList.get(position);
        if(asyncViewHolder != null){

            asyncViewHolder.setViews(view);

            if (asyncViewHolder.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.PENDING) {
                asyncViewHolder.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
            }

        }

        return view;
    }
```

My Async holder class is as follows:

```
public class ProgressBarTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    private static final String TAG = ProgressBarTask.class.getName().toString();

    private String title;

    public TextView mProgressTitle;
    public ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    public TextView mProgressPercent;


    public ProgressBarTask(String text){
        title = text;
    }

    public void setViews(View base){
        mProgressTitle = (TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.progress_title);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) base.findViewById(R.id.progress_horizontal);
        mProgressPercent = (TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.progress_percent);

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... ignore) {
        for (int i = 0; !isCancelled() && i < 100; i++) {
            if(i%5 == 0){
                Log.i(TAG, title + " publishProgress(" + i + "%)");
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            publishProgress(i);
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... percent) {
        if(percent[0]%5 == 0){
            Log.i(TAG, title +" onProgressUpdate(" + percent[0] + "%)");
        }
        mProgressBar.setProgress(percent[0] * mProgressBar.getMax() / 100);
        mProgressPercent.setText(percent[0] + "%");
    }
...
...
}
```

And my list_item is described as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/progress_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:text="Progress:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_horizontal"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:max="213"
        android:padding="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/progress_percent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:text="0%"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried a lot of different ways to make this work. Can someone please  explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: How is `mList` constructed and handed its contents? Is the text moving too, or just the progress bars?

Comment: mList is a list of ProgressBarTasks. When I click a button in a different fragment a new list item (row) is added to mList and the ProgressBar starts immediately.

Comment: Is it possible that the returned `ProgessBarTask` is not the one you were expecting? Is your progress percent text getting mixed up too, or just the progress bars?

Comment: Yes the percent text is also getting mixed up. I have been reading that the ListView will automatically try to re-use list items when they are scrolled in/out of view. I believe that this may be something I need to control but I cannot figure out how to ensure the items are ordered and only the correct item is updated from the asynctask.

Comment: Yes its called view recycling, and for performance reasons you'll want to work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you scroll, what was at `position` 5, is now --for instance-- at 1 now.

Your code then says `mList.get(1)`, when the `ProgressBarTask` that you're actually looking for is `mList.get(5)`, because it was created at `position` 5 when stored in `mList`.

In a nutshell, `position` only corresponds to the correct index for `mList` when there is less than one page of content. As soon as you scroll, the indexes become "out of sync".

Consider using an `ArrayAdapter` to make your life easier.

Comment: Ok, Thanks I will try an ArrayAdapter instead of BaseAdapter.

Comment: @McGee, consider accepting my answer if you feel I've helped you.